# Check delivery report of sms sent from other application

Tags: android, sms

Can we track the messages sent from other application? I mean, when user send sms by android default sms application (or other sms-managing application), can we track the sms situation and make a notification in our application when sms delivered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible, unless that other app specifically has an API to support such monitoring.